# 4 way circuit with two 4 way switches

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting

I have a 4 way circuit (3 physical toggle switches).  I am use to seeing this setup with two 3-ways and a 4-way in the middle. Looking at what I have, I have a 3-way, and two 4-way switches! All 4 terminals on both 4 ways have wires. There is not a 4th switch anywhere.  One of those 4-ways should be a 3-way. Would one of those wires into the 4-way be useless? Is this just a different way to wire up a 4-way? In the end, I want to remove the 4 way and just be left with 2 switches in a normal 3 way. I thought I could just remove the 4 way, connect the travelers and be left with a 3 way, but I'm not sure what to do with the second 4-way.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: If you splice travelers straight through, the status of any useless wire will remain unchanged. You do need to leave the splice box accessible.

Comment: Thank you, I understand. My issue is, I plan on eventually replacing with a smart switch. So I will eventually need to figure out which of the 4 wires is not being used. Wonder if I just need to start trying to remove one at a time and see which one is not needed?

Comment: Do the three switches function correctly, each turning the light on or off?.

Comment: Yes. Everything works as expected

Comment: Any chance we can get photos of what is going on inside that junction box?  What the wires are grouped with is quite important.

Comment: Can we have photos of the insides of all boxes involved please?

Answer (score 1):

Someone probably misunderstood the requirements or changed plans. One conductor is probably unnecessary at the end of the circuit.

Refer to standard 4-way wiring as a guide and see if you can replicate it with your wires.

[image]

Comment: Would I just try removing one of the Black terminal wires from a 4-way and see if it still works? Repeating until I find the unnecessary wire? Thanks

Comment: Difficult to say without seeing a diagram of your existing wiring. I don't do this for a living and can't picture your scenario reliably in my head.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to waste everyone's time. It was two 3-ways and a 4-way after all. Somehow I saw 4 wires but when I pulled it all out I saw it was just 3. Sorry again.